# python Hypothesis test with optional parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-hypothesis

On my project, I am using `Hypothesis` to test a function.
The function under testing accept one mandatory argument called `stop` and two optional parameters called respectively `start` and `step`.
If the parameter `step` is zero, the code under test should trigger an exception.

Here is my test function

```
@given(start=st.integers(min_value=-1000, max_value=1000),
       stop=st.integers(min_value=-1000, max_value=1000),
       step=st.integers(min_value=-1000, max_value=1000))
@settings(settings(verbosity=Verbosity.verbose))
def test_XXX_for_integer(start, stop, step):
    if step == 0:
        with raises(ValueError) as excinfo:
            _ = myrange3(start, stop, step)
        assert 'arg 3 must not be zero' in str(excinfo.value)
    else:
        output = <some code>
        expected = <some output> 
        assert output == expected
```

MY QUESTION: I would like to also simulate the fact that `start` and `step` is optional and therefore one or both of these parameters are set to `None`.  How can I do that without recreating a dedicated test function for each variation of the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join strategies the same way you join sets. Example:

```
strategy_bools_or_ints = st.booleans() | st.integers()
```

In the test, you could join `st.integers` with `st.none`:

```
st_input = st.integers(min_value=-1000, max_value=1000)
st_input_optional = st_input | st.none()

@given(start=st_input_optional, stop=st_input, step=st_input_optional)
def test_XXX_for_integer(start, stop, step):
    assert myrange3(stop, start=start, step=step)
```